# Google Apps script - Run function in subfolder

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm already have some script function on google script and now i need to rub this script in every subfolder not the same time but one vt one EX = (If finish run on subfolder 1 then it automatic run on subfolder 2 until it finish all sub folder)

Any advice about this thank you in advance or Is it possible to such thing like this?

Comment: I tried editing your question but I could not figure what you are saying.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

#### Perhaps you want to recurse subfolders:

```
var level = 1;
function recFldrs(folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder()) {
  if(folder) {
    //run your code
  }
  const subfolders = folder.getFolders()
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
    let subfolder = subfolders.next();
    level++;
    recFldrs(subfolder);
  }
  level--;
}
```